# How to efficiently find the ordinal number of an element in a strictly increasing python list?

Tags: python

I can only think of iterating through the list, but that's highly inefficient as the list can grow as big as 1000000.

**EDIT**: I also know about binary search. I would like to know if there is any builtin python function which can do this efficiently.

Comment: With a binary search you can go down from O(N) to O(logN).

Comment: You should probably buy a basic book on datastructures and algorithms. Although the concepts are easy to understand, even the idea of using a binary search was first worked out by cutting edge geniuses. Stand on their shoulders.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks Marcin. I want to know if there is a builtin python function which can do that.

Comment: @thefourtheye Well, then I suggest that you look at the list of builtin modules. But still, if you'd known about binary search, I imagine you would just have googled it and been happy. So, I'm assigning you two readings now. ;)

Comment: @Marcin I am going through each and every module which I hvnt heard about... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module. The docs suggest the following for locating an element in a sorted list:

```
def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError
```